# Vue share components and assets between two projects

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

What is the best way to share components and assets between two projects? I've tried creating a local npm package using npm link, but when I build it says the dependency is not found. Is there a good way to do this?

Also, will the assets still be minified/tagged if they are in a different assets directory then the main one in the project?

Comment: Are you sure you npm linked the package correctly? You did npm link in the library to share and npm link <linked library name> in the other project? To share assets, I suggest using Firebase Storage: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start

Comment: I did npm link in both places. And thanks, I'll take a look at Firebase Storage!

Comment: Could you please post how you exactly import the linked module and what is the 
 whole stacktrace?